# MS Access "duplicate values" error, but I don't know why

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I have a VB6 program that adds a column to an MS Access database thusly:

```
alter table x add column y long constraint z unique
```

The program goes through a number of databases without error; however, on the one that I am looking at now, it gives me "The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship..."

In case it makes a difference, I add values to the column by forming a recordset of the primary key and new column values, then going through each record to add a value to this column. I do `recordSet.updateBatch` when I'm all done.

If I remove the constraint, it completes normally; I have put all 1600 values into a spreadsheet, sorted by the values I've added, and used a formula to check for duplicates.  There aren't any.  All rows get a new value, none of the new values are the same as any other new value.

Are there other reasons why I might get this error?  I really don't want to remove the constraint, but I don't know how to get past this.

Comment: Perhaps you could show us the table definition, and the statement you are using to update it?

Comment: Well, the statement that adds the field is
    "alter table citation add column long_citeIndex long constraint k_index unique".  I don't think you want the whole table definition, it has many fields in it, and I don't think it's relevant.

The update code has: "select x, y from z", then "rs.fields("y").value = [calculated value]" in a loop that goes through all 1600 records, then "rs.UpdateBatch".  And those all work if I remove the constraint from the column addition.

Comment: Please clarify which step triggers the error.  At first I thought you were saying it happened with the ALTER TABLE.  But reading again, sounds like the error happens later when you INSERT.  Which is right?

Comment: I apologize; my bafflement has evidently befuddled me.  This happens when I do the "recordset.UpdateBatch".

Comment: I am ready to drop the question entirely; I've become convinced that this error is caused by some attribute of this particular database instance, and that I won't have the problem on other databases (just like I already do not have it on existing databases).  I appreciate everyone's help.

Comment: Logically, your statement SHOULD give an error on any table having more than 1 record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're certain you're not attempting to insert rows which violate the table's index constraints, perhaps you have a corrupted index.  See whether Compact & Repair cures the problem.  But first make a backup of the database.

You could also recreate the table in a new database and test it there.

You can find further information about corruption at Tony Towes' [Corrupt Microsoft Access MDBs FAQ](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/corruptmdbs.htm).